# What are the *disadvantages* to net neutrality?

Tags: routing

I've heard all the arguments for net neutrality, Stack Exchange has a link on my screen arguing for it after all, and I can see some real points in them.  However, for anyone to make an informed decision they need to know both sides of an argument.

So what are the supposed disadvantages of net neutrality?  What potential costs to consumers, service providers, websites, or the internet as a whole that could theoretically occure if Net Neutrality was enacted?

To be more specific I'm interested in Net Neutrality as it's currently argued as being enforced by the FCC.  That is to say considering ISPs a "Title II" to being a "Title 2"